# SSH Permission denied (publickey,password) from internet

Tags: ssh, permissions, dynamic-dns

I´d been successfully connecting through SSH into my Ubiquiti radios (5 of them) through internet (DDNS) for a while but since a couple weeks ago with the exact same credentials I can´t, only one of them is still allowing me to connect, the other four are giving me permission denied. I already changed passwords and port numbers (user name is the same for all) but no luck. Here is my -v print out of the one is working:

```
C:\Users\Familia>ssh -v -l ubnt somethingelse.ddns.net -p5678 -D8080
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to somethingelse.ddns.net [xxx.yyy.zzz.239] port 5678.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear
debug1: no match: dropbear
debug1: Authenticating to somethingelse.ddns.net:5678 as 'ubnt'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:MTm4u31b1jCCganvaF02np8Wsc+fX7DCGMieGnUH3s0
debug1: Host '[somethingelse.ddns.net]:5678' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubnt@somethingelse.ddns.net's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to somethingelse.ddns.net ([xxx.yyy.zzz.239]:5678).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8080 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: console supports the ansi parsing
 ___  ___
|\  \|\  \      Welcome to airOS
\ \  \\\  \
 \ \  \\\  \    PRODUCT: PowerBeam 5AC 620
  \ \  \\\  \   MAC: 788SDGE567D7
   \ \_______\
    \|_______|  VERSION: XC.v8.6.2

XC#
XC#
XC#
XC#
XC# exit
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3
debug1: channel 0: free: port listener, nchannels 2
debug1: channel 1: free: port listener, nchannels 1
Connection to somethingelse.ddns.net closed.
Transferred: sent 2152, received 1736 bytes, in 2.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1007.4, received 812.6
debug1: Exit status 0
```

and one I can´t:

```
C:\Users\Familia>ssh -v -l ubnt something.ddns.net -p1234 -D8080
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to something.ddns.net [xxx.yyy.zzz.239] port 1234.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear
debug1: no match: dropbear
debug1: Authenticating to something.ddns.net:1234 as 'ubnt'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:MTm4u31b1jCCganvaF02np8Wsc+fX7DCGMieGnUH3s0
debug1: Host '[something.ddns.net]:1234' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Familia/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubnt@something.ddns.net's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubnt@something.ddns.net's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
ubnt@something.ddns.net's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubnt@something.ddns.net: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I would like to add that I´m using Command Prompt in Windows 10 and from LAN I can connect to all of them using the same credentials without any issue. Can anybody help me please??

Comment: It seems a bit odd to me that both boxes have the same server host key. Are those the original logs, or have you altered them?

Comment: those are the original...

Comment: In this case you should check your router's settings. It seems that both open ports (1234 and 5678) route traffic to the same box.